# EF Core ошибка при добавлении записи в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Получаю ошибку:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetRoles'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate
>   key value is (914b2e13-5b2d-44b6-a288-7b6ac432c62b).

И не понимаю чего он вообще трогает эту таблицу `dbo.AspNetRoles`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<String> EditRole(string roleId, List<string> permissions)
{
    MyIdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

    if (role == null)
        NotFound();

    //Получаем разрешение текущей роли
    List<Permission> permissionsRole = _permissionRoleContext.PermissionRole.Where(p => p.Role == role).Select(p => p.Permission).ToList();
    //Получаем устанавливаемые разрешения
    var setPermissions = _permissionContext.Permission.Where(p => permissions.Contains(p.Id.ToString())).ToList();

    foreach(Permission per in setPermissions)
    {
        var perRole = new PermissionRole() { Permission = per, Role = role };

        _permissionRoleContext.Add(perRole);
    }

    _permissionRoleContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Контекст данных:

```
public class PermissionRoleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PermissionRole> PermissionRole { get; set; }

    public PermissionRoleContext(DbContextOptions<PermissionRoleContext> options):base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
public class PermissionRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyIdentityRole Role { get; set; }

    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Может, потому что вы указываете роль тут `var perRole = new PermissionRole() { Permission = per, Role = role };` ? Вот эта роль `Role = role` - она же была не через контеекст получена и не приаттачена к контексту

Comment: @tym32167 я переделал к отношению многие к многим и вообще повис окончательно. Я ненавижу ASP.NET Core, как было хорошо раньше когда можно было просто написать "INSERT Into table1"  и все без этого всего гемороя, который якобы должен был облегчить

Comment: Ну не знаю, я сам использую EF Code First (MySQL) + Asp.Net core 2, и у меня проблем пока нет никаких. Буквально на днях начну делать что то типа того, что вы делаете, только чуть сложнее (отдельные пермишены на отдельные сущности в БД  будут нвстраиваться админом), так что ваш опыт мне пригодится :)

Comment: _ненавижу ASP.NET Core_ - а как эта ненависть относится к вопросу? У вас проблема с _EntifyFramework - ORM для доступа к базе данных_, а не с _web-фреймворком_. Никто и ничто не запрещает в ASP.NET Core выполнять обычные sql-запросы.

Comment: Дополню. Если вам не нравится EF, вы можете его просто удалить из своего приложения. И работать с БД с помощью вручную написанных sql-запросов через ADO.NET.

Comment: ну да, если прямо руками хочется писать код, то Dapper самое то